# PHP: subtract a DateTime range to another DateTime range

Tags: php, datetime

```
function dateIntervalDiff( array &$sets, array &$exclusions )
{   // SUBTRACT DATETIME EXCLUSIONS TO DATETIME SETS
    foreach( $sets as $i => &$set )
    {
        foreach( $exclusions as &$exclusion )
        {
            if( $exclusion[ 'start' ] <= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] >= $set[ 'end' ] )
                unset( $sets[ $i ] );
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] <= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] <= $set[ 'end' ] )
                $set = [ 'start' => ( clone $set[ 'end' ] )->modify( '-' . ( $set[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() - $exclusion[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ), 'end' => $set[ 'end' ] ];
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] >= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] >= $set[ 'end' ] )
                $set = [ 'start' => $set[ 'start' ], 'end' => ( clone $set[ 'start' ] )->modify( '+' . ( $exclusion[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() - $set[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ) ];
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] >= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] <= $set[ 'end' ] )
            {
                $sets[] = [ 'start' => $set[ 'start' ], 'end' => ( clone $set[ 'start' ] )->modify( '+' . ( $exclusion[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() - $set[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ) ];
                $sets[] = [ 'start' => ( clone $set[ 'end' ] )->modify( '-' . ( $set[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() - $exclusion[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ), 'end' => $set[ 'end' ] ];
                unset( $sets[ $i ] );
                return dateIntervalDiff( $sets, $exclusions );
            }
        }
    }
    usort( $sets, function( $a, $b ) { return ( $a[ 'start' ] )->getTimestamp() - ( $b[ 'start' ] )->getTimestamp(); } );
    return $sets;
}

// FUNCTION TEST CODE

$sets = [
    [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 23:59:59', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ]
];
$exclusions = [
    [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 9:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 13:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ]/*,
    [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 14:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 18:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ]*/
];

foreach( dateIntervalDiff( $sets, $exclusions ) as $current )
    echo 'From ' . $current[ 'start' ]->format( DateTime::ATOM ) . ' to ' . $current[ 'end' ]->format( DateTime::ATOM ) . '<br />';
```

With **one item** in "exclusions" list it work ( Output:
*From 2022-07-04T00:00:00+00:00 to 2022-07-04T09:00:00+00:00

From 2022-07-04T13:00:00+00:00 to 2022-07-04T23:59:59+00:00* )

With **two or more items**, the script crashes after an infinite loop ( Desired output:
*From 2022-07-04T00:00:00+00:00 to 2022-07-04T09:00:00+00:00

From 2022-07-04T13:00:00+00:00 to 2022-07-04T14:00:00+00:00

From 2022-07-04T18:00:00+00:00 to 2022-07-04T23:59:59+00:00* )

what do you think is the solution to the problem?

What I want to do is, starting from an initial timeline, remove portions of time that eventually overlap the timeline (composed of its fragments) and obtain a final list of the remaining intervals

**Update 05/07/2022: solved updating the second and third "if" controls.
Final function:**

```
function dateIntervalDiff( array &$sets, array &$exclusions ): array
{   // SUBTRACT DATETIME EXCLUSIONS TO DATETIME SETS
    foreach( $sets as $i => &$set )
    {
        foreach( $exclusions as &$exclusion )
        {
            if( $exclusion[ 'start' ] <= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] >= $set[ 'end' ] )
                unset( $sets[ $i ] );
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] < $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] > $set[ 'start' ] )
                $set = [ 'start' => ( clone $set[ 'end' ] )->modify( '-' . ( $set[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() - $exclusion[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ), 'end' => $set[ 'end' ] ];
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] < $set[ 'end' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] > $set[ 'end' ] )
                $set = [ 'start' => $set[ 'start' ], 'end' => ( clone $set[ 'start' ] )->modify( '+' . ( $exclusion[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() - $set[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ) ];
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] >= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] <= $set[ 'end' ] )
            {
                $sets[] = [ 'start' => $set[ 'start' ], 'end' => ( clone $set[ 'start' ] )->modify( '+' . ( $exclusion[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() - $set[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ) ];
                $sets[] = [ 'start' => ( clone $set[ 'end' ] )->modify( '-' . ( $set[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() - $exclusion[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ), 'end' => $set[ 'end' ] ];
                unset( $sets[ $i ] );
                return dateIntervalDiff( $sets, $exclusions );
            }
        }
    }
    usort( $sets, function( $a, $b ) { return ( $a[ 'start' ] )->getTimestamp() - ( $b[ 'start' ] )->getTimestamp(); } );
    return $sets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked.

```
    function dateIntervalDiff( array &$sets, array &$exclusions )
{   // SUBTRACT DATETIME EXCLUSIONS TO DATETIME SETS
    foreach( $sets as $i => &$set )
    {
        foreach( $exclusions as &$exclusion )
        {
            if( $exclusion[ 'start' ] <= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] >= $set[ 'end' ] )
                unset( $sets[ $i ] );
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] <= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] <= $set[ 'end' ] )
                $set = [ 'start' => ( clone $set[ 'end' ] )->modify( '-' . ( $set[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() - $exclusion[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ), 'end' => $set[ 'end' ] ];
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] >= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] >= $set[ 'end' ] )
                $set = [ 'start' => $set[ 'start' ], 'end' => ( clone $set[ 'start' ] )->modify( '+' . ( $exclusion[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() - $set[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ) ];
            elseif( $exclusion[ 'start' ] >= $set[ 'start' ] && $exclusion[ 'end' ] <= $set[ 'end' ] )
            {
                $sets[] = [ 'start' => $set[ 'start' ], 'end' => ( clone $set[ 'start' ] )->modify( '+' . ( $exclusion[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() - $set[ 'start' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ) ];
                $sets[] = [ 'start' => ( clone $set[ 'end' ] )->modify( '-' . ( $set[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() - $exclusion[ 'end' ]->getTimestamp() ) . ' seconds' ), 'end' => $set[ 'end' ] ];
                unset( $sets[ $i ] );
                return dateIntervalDiff( $sets, $exclusions );
            }
        }
    }
    usort( $sets, function( $a, $b ) { return ( $a[ 'start' ] )->getTimestamp() - ( $b[ 'start' ] )->getTimestamp(); } );
    return $sets;
}

// FUNCTION TEST CODE

$sets = [
    [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 23:59:59', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ],
     [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 23:59:59', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ],
     [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 23:59:59', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ]
];
$exclusions = [
    [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 9:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 13:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ],
    [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 9:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 13:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ],
    [
        'start' => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 9:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) ),
        'end'   => new DateTime( '2022-07-04 13:00:00', new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) )
    ]
    
];

foreach( dateIntervalDiff( $sets, $exclusions ) as $current )
    echo 'From ' . $current[ 'start' ]->format( DateTime::ATOM ) . ' to ' . $current[ 'end' ]->format( DateTime::ATOM ) . '<br />';
```